# Optimise Performance of select statement (with sub query) in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have one requirement which is as follows.

```
create table bom_master (ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,label int, product varchar(20),PRIMARY KEY (ID));
```

Insert statements :-

```
insert into bom_master (label,product)values(1,'Budwieser');
insert into bom_master (label,product)values(2,'Heineken');
insert into bom_master (label,product)values(2,'Miller');
insert into bom_master (label,product)values(3,'Castle lite');
insert into bom_master (label,product)values(4,'Castle lager');
insert into bom_master (label,product)values(4,'Haywards');
insert into bom_master (label,product)values(3,'Kingfisher');
insert into bom_master (label,product)values(4,'Feni');
```

And this is the select statement output.

```
mysql> select * from bom_master;
+----+-------+--------------+
| ID | label | product      |
+----+-------+--------------+
|  1 |     1 | Budwieser    |
|  2 |     2 | Heineken     |
|  3 |     2 | Miller       |
|  4 |     3 | Castle lite  |
|  5 |     4 | Castle lager |
|  6 |     4 | Haywards     |
|  7 |     3 | Kingfisher   |
|  8 |     4 | Feni         |
+----+-------+--------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see the label column which depicts the label of each product. The immediate next label is the child of the previous label.
just for here 2 is the child of 1, next 2 is the child of same 1, then 3 is the child of 2 (the one that is immediate predecessor of 3). then 4 is the child of 3, next 4 is the child of same 3, then 3 is the child of the 2 with Miller as the product. And this follows.

To achieve this , this is the select statement, I am using. But the performance is quite slow . For 10000 records it is taking 6-7 minutes to fetch. But 50000 records it is taking more than a hour.

```
mysql> select label_parent, label_child, product_parent, product_child
    -> from   (select t3.*,
    ->                @row_num := IF(@prev_value=t3.id_child,@row_num+1,1) as rn,
    ->                @prev_value := t3.id_child
    ->         from   (select t1.label label_parent, t2.label label_child,
    ->                        t1.product product_parent, t2.product product_child,
    ->                        t1.id id_parent, t2.id id_child
    ->                 from   bom_master t1 join bom_master t2
    ->                 on     (t1.label = t2.label - 1 and t1.id < t2.id)) t3,
    ->                (select @row_num := 1) x,
    ->                (select @prev_value := '') y
    ->         order  by t3.id_child, t3.id_parent desc) t4
    -> where  rn = 1
    -> order  by id_child;
+--------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
| label_parent | label_child | product_parent | product_child |
+--------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
|            1 |           2 | Budwieser      | Heineken      |
|            1 |           2 | Budwieser      | Miller        |
|            2 |           3 | Miller         | Castle lite   |
|            3 |           4 | Castle lite    | Castle lager  |
|            3 |           4 | Castle lite    | Haywards      |
|            2 |           3 | Miller         | Kingfisher    |
|            3 |           4 | Kingfisher     | Feni          |
+--------------+-------------+----------------+---------------+
```

I have tried indexing as well.

```
create index bom_master_label_id_idx on bom_master (label, id);
```

How to improve the performance?

Comment: Can you change table structure, because this one is not optimal for your case?

Comment: Which way i can change the table structure. ??

Comment: I'll add it as an answer because it would be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `label` logic in the following way - change `label` to parentId (not necessary but it will be easier to understand without the need of documentation for it).
So the `parentId` will hold the `ID` of the parent. For example if Miller is label of Heineken, and Heineken is label of Budweiser you would have:

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| ID | parentId | product   |
+----+-------+--------------+
|  1 |     0 | Budwieser    |
|  2 |     1 | Heineken     |
|  3 |     2 | Miller       |
+----+-------+--------------+
```

Having `parentId = 0` will mean that this product don't have any parent.

So you wouldn't need of complex logic for the order of the products in the table.

And for further optimisation you can add additional `path` column which will hold the path to the parent for each child product.
For example:

```
+----+-------+--------------+--------------+
| ID | parentId | product   | path         |
+----+-------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 |     0 | Budwieser    |              |
|  2 |     1 | Heineken     | |1|          |
|  3 |     2 | Miller       | |2|1|        |
+----+-------+--------------+--------------+
```

`|` - is the separator. But this `path` will need some logic in your code when you `insert` or `update` a product. When inserting you will have to get the parent path of the current product and append it with the parent ID.

If you add Miller for example and you choose Heineken for its parent you will get Heineken's path (which is `|1|`) and append it with `2|` (Heineken's ID)

Comment: The thing is that i cant change the select statement . The select * from bom_master gives the same result as mentioned above. The complex query i have provided can we split the query into two and run it . ??